# Error Code: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I have a very strange problem with this code:

```
Update creature_template SET health_min=(health_min * 0.03) where entry in (select entry from creature where rank ='1');
Update creature_template SET health_max=(health_max * 0.03) where entry in (select entry from creature where rank ='1');
```

> Error occured at:2021-01-07 13:27:46
> Line no.:1
> Error Code: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='1')' at line 1

I use mysql 8.x and I am a beginner. in mysql 5.x this problem does not exist.
Anyone if can help i would be grateful.

Comment: Possibly rank is an integer and so should use rank=1   rather than ='1' which is comparing it to a string? If you can post samples of the data, might be able to assist further.

Answer (score 1):

`rank` is a reserved word in [MySQL since version 8.0.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). You need to escape it with backticks

```
... where `rank` = '1' ...
```